# Pop-up is showing in tab on IE8 but I need it in its own window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

I know someone else asked this recently, but I haven't seen an answer up there yet. I have a popup music player working with a WordPress website. Getting it to work was tricky and now I'm told the client sees it loading as a tab instead of a new window, which he absolutely won't accept. I wonder if there is absolutely no way to make this work?

```
function popUp() {
    var popup=window.open('http://websitehere.com?id=somevar&more=anothervar','','width=495,height=250,scrollbars=0');
}
```

And here's the call, in a link:

```
<a href="javascript:popUp();"><img src="theimage.png"></a>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there better popup code out there? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. Whether `window.open()` opens the url in a new window or a new tab is controlled by the user's browser's preferences, and cannot be overridden.

Comment: So this site is targeted at senior citizens. Do you know by experience at all how many people have this setting? Is it common? From what I saw on the MS website, it looks like you have to set it up that way on purpose, but the guy doesn't know, so I doubt he set it himself.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in an object element, or an iframe, in a div tricked out to look and act like a draggable, closable 'window'. Wait'll the client finds out some setups prevent **any** new windows being opened via script.